# Errors when attempting to publish aspx files via webdav

Tags: .net, iis-6, asp.net, webdav

After I installed the .net framework 3.5 to my IIS box (which didn't have any previous version of .net framework), I'm not long able to upload the aspx page via `WebDav` with MS Expression Web. I got this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Also I got this error `Server Application Unavailable` when trying to open the aspx page. my IIS box is not a domain controller nor a backup domain controller.

I have enabled the webservices extention - `ASP.NET v2.0.50727` and `WebDAV;

and still no luck, Help please!

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved the second question about the "Server Application Unavailable" by changing the "Execute Permission:" in Application settings from "Scripts Only" to "Scripts and Executable".

I am not sure if this setting is safe or recommended but it enables my aspx pages to be called and run.

any advices?! thanks!